# Fill the NA value in one column according to values of similar columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, nan

I want to fill the value of the nan in the given value as following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa'], 
                   'B': ['xx', 'yy', 'zz','xx'], 
                   'C': ['2', '3','8', np.nan]})
print (df)

A  B  C
aa xx 2
bb yy 3
cc zz 8
aa xx NaN
```

Expected Output:

```
A  B  C
aa xx 2
bb yy 3
cc zz 8
aa xx 2
```

Since column A and B have value 2 in the third column, therefore last row should also have 2 in the C column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for `NaN`s to end of groups:

```
df['C'] = df.sort_values(['A','B','C']).groupby(['A','B'])['C'].ffill().sort_index()
print (df)
    A   B  C
0  aa  xx  2
1  bb  yy  3
2  cc  zz  8
3  aa  xx  2
```

Another solution with forward and back filling per groups:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Answer (score 1):

try sort_values first to make Nan in last and then use group by with ffill()

```
df.sort_values(by=['C'],inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['A','B']).ffill()
```

```
    A   B   C
0   aa  xx  2
1   bb  yy  3
2   cc  zz  8
3   aa  xx  2
```

Comment: Working only if `NaN`s always last in groups, so generally not working...

Comment: yeah in this case we need to sort first so NaN should come last